# Unable to get related information from related list and display it on textbox on parent list using logged in user

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, spservices

I have two lists Created for my leave application in sharePoint. I need related information's come from related list (**Leaveinfo**) and display it on the textbox in Parent list (LeaveApply).

I have manged to display the logged in user on Empl: textbox in **Leaveapply** list. After that I want a comparison using Empl: field with **user** field of **Leaveinfo** list and get the related information called **Casual Leave** and display the information on **No. of days Required** field in **LeaveApply** list

Here are the two lists details

1. LeaveApply

   - EmpId
   - No. Of Days Required :

[image]

2. Leaveinfo

   - User
   - Casual Leave

[image]

Here is the code I have tried to achieve my solution, but it doesn't work for me to display **Casual Leave** value on  **No. of days Required** field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var userName = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
        fieldName: "Title"
    });
    $("input[Title='Empl:']").val(userName);

$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({ 
 relationshipList: "Leaveinfo",
 relationshipListParentColumn: "User",
 relationshipListChildColumn: "Casual Leave",
 parentColumn: "Empl:",
 childColumn: "No. Of Days Required :",
 debug: true });
});

</script>
```

I'm now believing that I have used the wrong logic as Cascade dropdown for this, and trying to achieve single data into textbox field rather than use the logic for Cascade dropdown.

can you please provide some sample javascript code to achieve this. I don't want to select any value on **Leave** list. Value should be filled automatically in the newform of **leave** list, and I'm using SharePoint foundation 2010, so can't go for Info-path as well.

Comment: Can someone provide any advice on how can we do this, please